# Como fazer leitura de String da melhor forma para usá-la como condição de parada de um laço?

Tags: c, string, loop, lógica

Estou tentando pedir entrada para uma string e lê-la como condição de parada de um laço mas não estou conseguindo. Erro na Lógica.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>


double calculoFatorial (double x) {


  //Variáveis
    double i,f = 1;

    //Lógica
    for(i = x; i > 0; i--){
        f = f * i;
    }

    //Retorno
    return (f);
}

int inicializando (void) {

    //Variáveis
    int fatoriando;
    double saida;

    //Código
    printf("\n - Me diga um número e direi seu fatorial: ");
    scanf("%d",&fatoriando);
    saida = calculoFatorial(fatoriando);
    printf(" - O fatorial do número %d é: %.lf",fatoriando,saida);

    //Retorno
    return (0);
}


int main (void){

    //Título 
    SetConsoleTitle("Calculadora de Fatorial");

    //Regionalizando
    printf("O idioma corrente no código é: %s\n",setlocale(LC_ALL,""));

    //Variáveis
    char resposta[1];

    //Lógica
    do{
        inicializando();
        printf("\n\n - Deseja fazer um novo calculo? (S/N): ");
        scanf("%s",resposta);
    }while(resposta[0] = "N");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Não tem sentido você declarar `char resposta[1];` pois uma string em C sempre acrescenta um caractere terminador '\0', por isso a string que deve armazenar um único caractere deve ter tamanho 2. No seu caso basta declarar `char resposta;` , isto é um único caractere e utliizar `scanf(" %c", &resposta);` e `}while(resposta == 'N');`. Mas se quiser trabalhar com strings então utilize a função `strcmp` para comparação.

Answer (score 2):

A comparação com `==` e `!=` não compara o conteúdo. A comparação de strings deve ser feita com `strcmp`.

**Substitua:**

```
do{
    inicializando();
    printf("\n\n - Deseja fazer um novo calculo? (S/N): ");
    scanf("%s",resposta);
}while(resposta[0] = "N");
```

**por:**

```
do{
    inicializando();
    printf("\n\n - Deseja fazer um novo calculo? (S/N): ");
    scanf("%s",resposta);
}while(strcmp(resposta, "S") == 0);
```